# jquery wait cursor while loading html in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to show to the user a state that the result is loading. 
How can I change cursor or gif while loading result in div with $MyDiv.load("page.php") ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Initially style the loading image non-visible.
2. Change the style to visible when you begin loading.
3. Change the style to non-visible when loading finished using a callback argument to load().

Example:

```
 $("#loadImage").show();
 $("#MyDiv").load("page.php", {limit: 25}, function(){
   $("#loadImage").hide();
 });
```

Comment: To actually create the loading gif, check out http://www.ajaxload.info/ where you can customize one and save it.

Answer (score 63):

```
$("body").css("cursor", "progress");
```

Just remember to return it afterwards:

```
$MyDiv.load("page.php", function () {
    // this is the callback function, called after the load is finished.
    $("body").css("cursor", "auto");
});
```

Comment: this did not work on my site but $("*").css("cursor", "progress") did

Comment: hmm... this approach has a bad side effect... setting $('*').css('cursor', 'auto') wipes away any special cursors you may have set up on items on the page.  no good!

Comment: @ekkis Do you know an alternative?

Comment: @ekkis Nevermind, I solved it by defining a css class `loading` where I set the cursor. And instead of $fnord.css(...) I use $fnord.toggleClass('loading')

Comment: This works for me unless I hover over a button.  Is there a way with CSS to set !important?

Comment: when going back to normal i used `$("body").css("cursor", "");`

Answer (score 12):

`$("*").css("cursor", "progress")`  will work no matter where on the page you are currently pointing.  This way you do not have to move the cursor to see it activated.

Comment: nice but does not work in Chrome (http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26723)

Comment: yikes! that approach is flawed. it wipes out cursor assignments to everything on the page.

Answer (score 10):

I think the best is to set up in css file

```
body.wait *, body.wait {
cursor:wait !important;
}
```

and add/remove class wait in body

this method overrides all cursors in inputs, links etc.

Comment: I like the approach but it didn't work on IE 9.  mountain's approach of `$('*').css('cursor', ...)` did though

Comment: yikes!  that approach is flawed.  it wipes out cursor assignments to everything on the page

Comment: This's actually the best cross-browser solution - tested. after removing wait class, CSS will cascade back to what the cursor was set without defaulting it like other solutions. Thx Marmot. 
@ekkis you should test it again. it works in IE9.

Answer (score 4):

I really think that it's a better solution to just use a class in the body element

```
  $('body').addClass('cursorProgress');
```

And when you want to keep it as it was before just:

```
  $('body').removeClass('cursorProgress');
```

and in you css file put something like that:

```
body.cursorProgress {
  cursor: progress;
}
```

So with this solution you are not overriding the defaults or changes you make on cursor styles, and the second advantage is that you have the possibility of adding the important in your css.

```
body.cursorProgress {
  cursor: progress !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want to show larger image on hovering on a thumbnail

```
//Hovered image
    $("a.preview").hover(function(e) {
            var aprev = this;
            //Show progress cursor while loading image
            $(aprev).css("cursor", "progress");
    //#imgpreview is the <div> to be loaded on hover
    $("#imgpreview").load(function() {           
                $(aprev).css("cursor", "default");
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner JQuery approach, although not necessarily efficient is to add and remove a busy class to all objects.

Note that, not all browsers (e.g. Firefox) assume a height of 100% for the outermost viewable object, so the busy cursor will only get displayed on the part of the screen

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .busy
        {
            cursor: wait !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

        $(function () {

            $("#btnToggleWait").click(function (e) {
                if ($(e.target).hasClass("busy")) {
                    $("*").removeClass("busy");
                }
                else {
                    $("*").addClass("busy");
                }

                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            });
        });

        //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <button id="btnToggleWait">
            Toggle Wait</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my solution, it covers all elements, not only the body tag:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26183551/1895428