# How to get cursor to change before mouse moves when changing the cursor style dynamically

Tags: javascript, css

I'm changing my cursor dynamically by setting node.style.cursor = 'foo' when an item becomes selected.  It seems that my cursor doesn't change until the mouse moves a pixel.

Is there a way to tell the browser to change it immediately?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718415/getting-the-browser-cursor-from-wait-to-auto-without-the-user-moving-the-mous

Comment: Thanks.  I searched but didn't come across that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with jQuery.

```
$(node).css('cursor', 'wait');
```

Or have a play with the changing of classes dynamically.

The css will be:

```
span.auto {cursor:auto}
span.wait {cursor:wait}
```

The javascript will be:

```
$(node).removeClass('auto');
$(node).addClass('wait);
```

Comment: Again, will the cursor change _before_ the mouse moves, with your code?