# jqgrid change pointer to hand

Tags: jqgrid

I want to change the pointer to hand when hovering over jqgrid's rows
Is there an API for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom formatter on any cell in the grid. For more info on these, see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter

Here's how I did it. I wanted the first column in my grid to appear like it is a clickable link (but really it triggers a custom jqgrid event, `onCellSelect`).

Snippet of my grid object:

```
colModel :[ 
{name:'ticket', index:'IMINDT', width:125, formatter: pointercursor},
```

pointercursor is a function name. The code for it is defined like this:

```
// Custom formatter for a cell in a jqgrid row. 
function pointercursor(cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{ 
var new_formatted_cellvalue = '<span class="pointer">' + cellvalue + '</span>'; 
return new_formatted_cellvalue; 
}
```

My CSS class of "pointer" is:

```
.pointer { 
cursor: pointer; 
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

That's it!

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of adding a span as it actually modifies the behavior of onCellSelect. If you click on the 'span' content it will NOT fire the onCellSelect event. Refer to Woggles answer as a possible work-around.

Answer (score 17):

This can be done more easily using the classes colModel property as below:

```
{ name: 'Email', index: 'Email', classes: 'pointer' }
```

From the wiki:

This option allow to add classes to the column. If more than one class will be used a space should be set. By example classes:'class1 class2' will set a class1 and class2 to every cell on that column. In the grid css there is a predefined class ui-ellipsis which allow to attach ellipsis to a particular row. Also this will work in FireFox too.

Answer (score 5):

I just add this into my css file

```
#mygrid .jqgrow{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in css file put this:

```
  .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-btable { cursor : pointer; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have not a jqgrid question, but pure CSS or javascript question. Look at [How to get cursor to change before mouse moves when changing the cursor style dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752372/how-to-get-cursor-to-change-before-mouse-moves-when-changing-the-cursor-style-dyn) for example. It shows how can one change **cursor** style of a html element. See also in http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html, that 'hand' is supported not in all browsers.