# Change cursor on background hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element (input) that has this code to give it a background on a small area (like a badge)

```
jQuery(this).css("background", "url(data:image/png;base64,<BASE64_ENCODED_DATA>) 99% 50% no-repeat scroll rgb(231, 248, 231)");
```

I want to make it so that when you hover the background the cursor will change to a pointer.
Thank you

Comment: specify css for `this` as `cursor:pointer;`

Comment: Like http://jsfiddle.net/oer797re/ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [js/css changing cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173666/js-css-changing-cursor)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(this).css({"background":"url(data:image/png;base64,<BASE64_ENCODED_DATA>) 99% 50% no-repeat scroll rgb(231, 248, 231)", "cursor":"pointer"});
```

or you can write css for that particular div

```
#particular_div{cursor:pointer;}
```

Hoping that the background is on `body` and the `.container` is the div for content then use

```
body:not(.container) {cursor:pointer;}
```

Comment: This is not what I ment, I want to cursor to change only when the mous is on top of the background image, not the entire element

Answer (score 1):

Let the div on which you want the cursor to be changed be #div1. So just change the CSS and use the `cursor` tag. You don't require JS

```
#div1{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```