# jQuery + CSS cursor mousedown + Chrome = not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cursor

I decided to make/test Cursors cross-browser, so far on Firefox its working perfect, but on Chrome - somewhat..

Now, the custom cursor shows, but when you click somewhere, it doesn't change, it does trigger mousedown event, but it doesn't change the cursor. I tried just mousedown(); and it changed the cursor. I guess the the mouseup event is causing this trouble.

```
$("body").mousedown(function() {
    $("body").addClass("clicked");
    console.log("down");
});
$("body").mouseup(function() {
    $("body").removeClass("clicked");
    console.log("up");
});
```

CSS

```
    body {
        cursor: url("../img/cursor1.cur"), default;
    }
    .clicked {
        cursor: url("../img/cursor2.cur"), default;
    }
```

Comment: So ... what does the CSS look like?

Comment: What cursor are you trying to add? Can you post the CSS?

Comment: Can you provide absolute urls to those two cursors?

Comment: [This should work properly](http://jsfiddle.net/kxuYq/1/). I'm guessing you just missed that your 'body' element has no layout... See @Sam s answer.

Comment: @sg3s http://www.highhigh.magnumweb.com.br/img/cursor1.cur and http://www.highhigh.magnumweb.com.br/img/cursor2.cur Don't be confused, this is not website I'm editing.

Comment: See, now that makes the problem clear: http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/kxuYq/8/ works as you said in FF, Chrome does nothing with the 2nd cursor state and IE manages to reverse the effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clicking and moving the mouse.

I think chrome only changes cursor on mousemove.

EDIT: This is a known bug, see [Getting the browser cursor from "wait" to "auto" without the user moving the mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718415/getting-the-browser-cursor-from-wait-to-auto-without-the-user-moving-the-mous/1756367#1756367)

Comment: Ehh, what a shame. I guess I will have to use lame workaround. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried out the following:

```
$('body').mousedown(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
$('body').mouseup(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

The result was as expected, click down -> red BG, click up -> green BG

BUT: this only happened, when i assigned css: `html, body { height:100%; min-height:100%; }`
Without the CSS the events were not really working as "fluent" as they should be.

Little tip: with firebug (at least chrome dev tools) you can monitor events using the following snipped:

```
monitorEvents(  $$('body')[0] )
```

Hope this helped

Comment: I have no problems with mouse event. But thanks for trying to help.

Comment: ah ok, then i kinda misunderstood your problem, though i must admit i don't really understand your CSS, why not just assigning a:active cursor 2? Wheres the sense with the body.clicked?

Comment: I updated the CSS for you, since I didn't understand your question. But it doesn't change anything anyway.

Comment: ah okay, i see the problem now. It appears to have something to do with the cursor itself. My guess - and nothing more than this - is, that browsers just do specific stuff with the cursor when pressed. I can't get the "mousedown" even to change the cursor either, mouseup works. It just changes once i stop clicking the buttom. Keeping the mouse pressed is seen as "selecting-mode" so i get the selection "cursor:text"-cursor :S

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the global window.event object, and not jQuery's event object. window.event only works in some browsers, and it is not a W3C standard.

jQuery normalizes the event object so it's the same in all browsers. The event handler is passed that jQuery event object as a parameter. You should be using that.

```
$(".class_name").mousedown(function (e) {

  switch (e.which) {
    case 1: //leftclick
        //...
        break;
    case 3: //rightclick
        //...
        break;
  }
});
```