# getting a mouseenter event from a still mouse entering an animated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseevent

I'm writing a image carousel and due to some class adding/removing my css pointer as well as my mouseenter event don't seem to work properly.

```
$("img", ":not(.active)").on("click", function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  $("img").removeClass("active");
  $this.addClass("active");

  goto($this.index());
});
$("img").on("mouseenter", function() {
    console.log("silence");
});
function goto(i) {
  $(".images").animate({
    left: 55-i*310
  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rnfkqq6s/3/

please take a look at the fiddle and watch the console. when the mouse doesn't move while clicking, the mouseenter sometimes isn't beeing triggered. the same thing with the cursor. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not getting your problem what you want?

Comment: e.g. go to the fiddle, click on the right image so it becomes .active and moves to the center. but leave the mouse where it is when you click. if you haven't moved it, it will now be again on an "inactive" element but showing the wrong cursor. With the javascript events something similar is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This issue relates to a known bug:

See similar:
[Getting the browser cursor from "wait" to "auto" without the user moving the mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718415/getting-the-browser-cursor-from-wait-to-auto-without-the-user-moving-the-mou)

The bug report:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26723#c87