# How to change the cursor to default on loading

Tags: jquery, css, mouse-cursor

I have the following code to change the cursor when a hyperlink is clicked

```
        $('a').click(function () {
            $('*').css("cursor", "progress");
        });
```

When a link is clicked, the cursor changes to "progress" (i.e. wait cursor) exactly as expected. However, the problem is that the cursor remains "progress" after a new page is loaded.  It changes to default only after the mouse moves. This is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561379/jquery-wait-cursor-while-loading-html-in-div). Others expressed the same problem.

As described by the title, I hope to change the cursor to default when a page is loaded.

Comment: can you be more precise about what happens when you click on that link ? anyway, the way you modify your cursor should be: $('body').css("cursor","progress")

Comment: Sorry for that. I have just added the following sentence"When a link is clicked, the cursor changes to "progress" (i.e. wait cursor) exactly as expected". I did try  $('body').css("cursor","progress") before posting the question. I also tried $(this).css("cursor","progress") before posting the question. All of them behave the same - the cursor remains "progress" until the mouse moves.

Comment: That's not what I meant. What we need to know is when do you want your cursor so stop the progress animation.

Comment: Sorry again.  I have just added the following sentence: "As described by the title, I hope to change the cursor to default when a page is loaded." Thanks a lot for looking into this.

Comment: i'll assume you have a link that load an url to a special target window. So you just have to follow my example but bind to the onload event of that window.

Answer (score 8):

You didn't clearly specify how it's meant to be used but here's an example of how to perform the behaviour you describe with an ajax call:

```
$('a').click(function () {
    $('body').css('cursor', 'progress');
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.html",
      context: document.body,
      complete: function(){
       $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
      }
    });
} );
```

Comment: Thanks again for looking into this. I meant reversing the cursor to default when a new page is loaded after clicking a link.  A link could be something like the following <a href="foo.aspx">Foo</a>

Comment: if a new page is loaded into your window, the cursor will be brought back to its default at unload, again I think you meant with a specific target like: <a href="foo.aspx" target="popupwindow">Foo</a>. Then you have to access the document object of that window and listen to its on ready like this: $( popupWindow ) .ready( unsetcursorfunction )

Comment: but I suggest you abandon that idea, I think the browsers nowadays are cleary explicit enough to notify the user that a page is being loaded :)

Comment: The cursor remaining "progress" is true for every page of one of my web applications. Whenever a link is clicked, the cursor changes to "progress" and it remains progress after the target page is loaded. It changes to the default only after the mouse is moved. I have had this problem for a while and thought its solution had to be something rudimentary. After trying everything I could come up to no avail, I decided to post the question here.

Comment: Browsers (e.g. FF, IE) show "loading..." on the bottom left and they do only after mouse moves after clicking. I have found it is not adequate for some visitors who tend to keep clicking a link when they do not see anything loading soon.